# The Software center won't start anymore how to fix it?

Tags: software-center

My software center in Ubuntu 14:04 wont start anymore. Error that I received is below in screen shot. I'm new in Ubuntu. So, somebody can give me step by step instructions to solve the issues that you would be much more appreciated. Thank you in advance.. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with 14.04. Each time the computer started a dialog would appear stating - System program problem detected -do you want to report it now? When I tried to report it after awhile it would state that I didn't have enough ram to do it, and so I had to try to solve the problem myself. I realized that Ubuntu hadn't been updating my system lately which was quite unusual so I clicked on the Software Updater and it wouldn't connect either. My next approach was to open synaptic and look for anything that might help me. I noticed that the square in front of the update manager was gray with an exclamation mark which meant it needed to be upgraded. I right clicked on it and selected upgrade marked the other file it selected applied it, and after it finished quit synaptic. This time the system updater worked, and after downloading and installing about 210 mega-bytes and restarting, Ubuntu software center was working again. That' all I can tell you. I'm not an expert.